# Definition of Galilean structure in Arnold's book?

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, galilean-relativity

I am reading Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics.
He quickly introduces the notion of Galilean structure.  The universe is defined as the affine space $A^4$ and time is defined as a linear mapping t from $R^4$ to $R$.   And the time interval between two events in the universe is simply $t(b-a)$.

Don't we need an additional requirement that the linear mapping $t$ is essentially a projection on the temporal part of the affine space?  Otherwise, transformation of uniform motion would not preserve this time interval invariance.

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372843/

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/788787/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769697/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421425/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163560/226902

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no 'temporal part of the universe' until you make your affine space isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^3 \times \mathbf{R}$. What Arnold says is that you take two events in the universe, then this defines a vector in $\mathbf{R}^4$, and to that vector you see what the image of the time map $t:\mathbf{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is.