# Is time an invariant of Galilean transformation?

Tags: spacetime, time, coordinate-systems, galilean-relativity

Is time an invariant of Galilean transformation? By saying that I mean if there is a quantity analogous to spacetime interval in Lorentz transformation. What is the geometry of "Galilean spacetime"?

Comment: Time is absolute in the sense of Newtonian mechanics, and the quantity analogous to the spacetime interval of the Minkowski space is the distance between two points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space, which is invariant under Galilean transformations. The geometry is Euclidean.

Comment: @Lith So briefly speaking invariant consisting both spacial and time coordinates can be found only in Einstein's theory of relativity. The clue would then be: Galilean translation preserve distance in three spacial dimensions and time differences _separately_. Am I right now?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In Newtonian theory the space in which nature events exists is just the 3-dimensional Euclidean space, so time doesn't come into play when considering changes of coordinates. In Einstein's Relativity, since the transformations between inertial observers are time-dependent, it results natural to consider a 4-dimensional Minkowski space in which time is another coordinate. It is natural because in such case then the invariant interval maintains the typical form $ds=g_{\mu \nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$.

Comment: By the way, I guess most books start with the Galilean transformations before introducing the Lorentz transformations (in my GR classes we used [D'Inverno's "Introducing Einstein's Relativity"](https://www.amazon.com/Introducing-Einsteins-Relativity-Ray-dInverno/dp/0198596863), for example), so you will find all you need in any SR or GR book, and far better explained than in my comments!

Comment: @Lith (1) Galilean and Newtonian spacetimes are not the same (the Newtonian spacetime has an additional condition). (2) Neither of these spacetimes is Eucledian. The spatial part is, but spacetime is not the same as space, as it also includes time and the resulting tuple is not Eucledian. (3) The Galilean interval between two events is not the same as the spatial distance between them. The Galilean spacetime metric consists of two separate metrics for space and time.

Comment: Please see an answer to this question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372843/how-can-i-interpret-or-mathematically-formalize-maxwellian-leibnizian-and-mach/372869#372869

Comment: @safesphere I stand rigorously corrected! Thanks for the link.